# Flutter: How to do this emoji firework animation?

Tags: flutter, animation

I want to do this emoji fireworks animation in a flutter widget:
https://codepen.io/z3vin/pen/QEqqdY

The code is in TypeScript:

```
class Firework {
  constructor(app) {
    this.app = app;
    this.rnd = app.rnd;
    this.bursts = [];
    this.reset();
  }
  reset() {
    this.color = `hsl(${this.rnd.int(360)},90%,50%)`;
    this.alive = true;
    this.bursting = false;
    this.pos = new Vec( this.rnd.int(0,this.app.w), this.app.h+40 );
    this.vel = new Vec(0,-this.rnd.real(16.0,this.app.h/40));
    this.acc = new Vec(0,0);
    this.size = this.rnd.real(0.25,5.0);
    this.emoji = this.rnd.pick(this.app.emojis);
  }
  applyForce(f){
    this.vel.add(f);
  }
  update() {
    this.applyForce(this.app.forces.gravity);
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    if(this.vel.y > 1) {
      this.bursting = true;
      const maxBursts = Math.floor(this.app.w / 4);
      const numBursts = this.rnd.chance(5) ? this.rnd.int(100,maxBursts) : this.rnd.int(20,80);
      for(let i = 1; i < numBursts; i++){
        this.bursts.push(new Burst(this.pos, this));
      }
    }
      
  }
  draw() {
    const ctx = this.app.ctx;
    if(!this.bursting) {
      this.update();
      ctx.save();
      ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
      ctx.font = `${this.size}em sans-serif`;
      ctx.fillText(this.emoji,this.pos.x,this.pos.y);
      //ctx.fillRect(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.size, this.size);
      ctx.restore();
    } else {
      this.bursts.forEach(burst=>{
        if(!burst.alive){
          without(this.bursts,burst);
          if(this.bursts.length ===0){
            this.alive = false;
          }
        }
        burst.draw();
      });
    }
  }
}


class Burst {
  constructor(origin,firework){
    this.firework = firework;
    this.app = firework.app;
    this.pos = origin.clone();
    this.rnd = firework.rnd;
    this.lifespan = this.rnd.int(5,50);
    this.vel = new Vec(this.rnd.real(-8.0,8.0),this.rnd.real(-8.0,8.0));
    this.acc = new Vec(0,0);
    this.color = this.firework.color;
    this.size = this.rnd.real(0.5,15.0);
    const sparkle = this.rnd.chance(20) ? 2 : 1;
    this.sizeStep = this.size/(this.lifespan/sparkle);
    this.alive = true;
    this.rotate = this.rnd.real(0,Math.PI*2);
  }
  applyForce(f){
    this.vel.add(f);
  }
  update() {
    this.applyForce(this.app.forces.gravity);
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    //this.size -= this.sizeStep;
    //this.rotate += 0.1;
  }
  draw() {
    const ctx = this.app.ctx;
    this.update();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.pos.x,this.pos.y)
    ctx.rotate(this.rotate);
    ctx.font = `${this.firework.size/2}em sans-serif`;
    ctx.fillText(this.firework.emoji,0,0);
    ctx.restore();
    this.lifespan--;
    if(this.lifespan<=0){
      this.alive = false;
    }
  }
}

class App {
  constructor(){
    this.ctx = document.getElementById('cnv').getContext('2d');
    this.sizeCanvas();
    this.initEvents();
    this.rnd = new Random();
    this.fireworks = [];
    this.forces = {
      gravity: new Vec(0,0.25)
    };
    this.emojis = ['','','','☘','','','','⚡️','','','⚽️'];
    window.requestAnimationFrame((t)=>{this.draw(t)});
    log(this);
  }
  sizeCanvas(){
    this.w = this.ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.h = this.ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
  clearIt() {
    //this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.w,this.h);
    this.ctx.save();
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'hsla(220,60%,10%,0.12)';
    this.ctx.fillRect(0,0,this.w,this.h)
    this.ctx.restore();
  }
  draw(t){
    this.clearIt();
    window.requestAnimationFrame((t)=>{this.draw(t)});
    if(this.rnd.chance(this.w/80)){
      this.fireworks.push(new Firework(this));
    }
    this.fireworks.forEach(f=>{
      if(!f.alive){
        without(this.fireworks,f);
      }
      //log(this.fireworks.length)
      f.draw();
    });
  }
  initEvents(){
    window.onresize = (e)=>{this.sizeCanvas(e)};
  }
}


const foo = 'dsdsa';
const log = console.log.bind(console);
const Vec = TinyVector;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const app = new App();
});

function without (arr, el) {
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(el),1);
}
```

Can someone guide me to do this kind of UI making in flutter?

I'm desesperate to find the solution but i don't understand how animation works and i found nothing on stack or other website to do this.

Thanks a lot to people who know how to do that.

I already tried the confetti package but it's not my final goal.